# Single database connection with HibernateTemplate and SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jdbc

on the java side, everything works fine but when I look to the V$SESSION special oracle table , and in my log table that records any login or logoff operations, that's a disaster... every single query does a login/logoff operation. So here's my question : Is there any way to configure Spring to have a unique connection to the database or is there something wrong in the way I do the connection ?
Here, my datasource bean configuration :

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@nanssunorad:1523:nanorad3</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>foo</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>bar</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>hibernateESign.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="IXalVaParametresDAO" class="fr.asterion.archivage.hibernate.XalVaParametresDAO">
    <property name="sessionFactory">
        <ref local="sessionFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

In my app, to get the DAO for the database parameters, I do a

```
  IXalVaParametresDAO parametreDAO = (IXalVaParametresDAO) ConfigApplication
           .getApplicationContext(this.log).getBean("IXalVaParametresDAO");
```

And at last, in my DAO class, I do someting like this :

```
public class XalVaParametresDAO implements IXalVaParametresDAO
{

   private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;

   public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
   {
      this.hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
   }



   public List<XalVaParametres> findAll()
   {
      log.debug("finding all XalVaParametres instances");
      try
      {
         String queryString = "from XalVaParametres";
         List lst = this.hibernateTemplate.find(queryString);
```

In my app, each time I call the "find" method, it does a DB login/logoff. I guess the problem is the same on another DB. Am I doing the things right ? I guess not. I wish the HibernateTemplate would create and keep the session open once and for all. Is that possible ?
Thanks for your ideas

Manux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a pooling `DataSource`, e.g. [Apache Commons / DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/)'s [`BasicDataSource`](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/api-1.4/index.html?org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html)

**Reference:**

- [Spring JDBC > Controlling Database Connections](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-connections)
- [Spring ORM > Hibernate > SessionFactory setup in a Spring
  container](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-session-factory-setup)

Comment: Ok, I've tried with apache's BasicDataSource and it works very well ! And as axtavt said, the use of the DriverManagerDataSource is discouraged exactly because of the bad connection handles. Thank you all for your responses.

Comment: @MaryRyllo glad to be of help :-)

Comment: This one saved me. Spring was assigning a lot of connections apparently. The DBCP DS uses only 1. Absolutely splendid! :-D Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4):

It's not recommended to use `DriverManagerDataSource` in production, since it doesn't perform connection pooling.

You need to use connection pool instead, such as [c3p0](http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/) or [Apache DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/).

Answer (score 2):

Its better to use the connection pooling of the application server and specify the jndi in spring xml file :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/DSTest"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native oracle datasource with connection caching like:

```
<bean id="myDataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="URL">
            <value>${jdbc.url}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="user">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
            <value>
                MinLimit:1
                MaxLimit:1
                InitialLimit:1
                ConnectionWaitTimeout:120
                InactivityTimeout:180
                ValidateConnection:true
                MaxStatementsLimit:0
            </value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```