# Too many connections while using Hibernate and Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, connection

I use Spring and Hibernate in my project. I use such prop

```
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${chassis.storage.hibernate.dialect}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">${chassis.storage.hibernate.batch_size}</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</prop>
```

When I write some data I use such code

```
    getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
            for (Data data : datas) {
                session.persist(data);
            }
            session.flush();
            return null;
        }
    });
```

But I have an exception

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException:
>   Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from
>   server: "Too many connections"

I use `netstat -an | grep 3306` and see a lot of connections.
What is the problem, what do you think?

Comment: I'm guessing that you aren't closing your connections/sessions properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4067801/106261

Comment: @duffymo as I know Spring automatically close and open connections. I m mistaken?

Comment: Hibernate - sessions - don't assume.  Believe what the error is telling you and remedy it.

Comment: Spring discourages use of Hibernate templates. Consider upgradig to Hibernate 4 and use Spring's declarative transaction management

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was in datasource. I used

```
org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource
```

Now I use `org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource` and it works perfectly!

See similar question here - 
[Single database connection with HibernateTemplate and SessionFactory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341618/single-database-connection-with-hibernatetemplate-and-sessionfactory)

Answer (score 0):

You have a maximum of `<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</prop>` connections while [MySQL default number of connections is 151](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/too-many-connections.html), is your application the only one accessing that database instance? does not look like so. Even if your connections are left open (I doubt it while using c3p0) you have set a maximum of 50. Another possibility is a connection leak somewhere else, a JDBC code or configuration either Hibernate, Spring where you acquire additional connections.

UPDATE: maybe the MySQL number of connections `max_connections` configuration has been changed to a lower value.

UPDATE: use e.g. MySQL workbench and check where your database instance active connections are originating from.

Comment: My application is the only one accessing my database. Before start app I check it with netstat.

Comment: I use command show variables like "max_connections"; in mysql. It show 151 max connections.